# JavaScript to get Client IP Address bypassing Browser Extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, ip-address, browser-extension

I am using an external API and part of the parameter of the API is an IP address. I looked up how to do it and I used the [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/) version in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/12415287) because it has no limitations. Here is the script:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(data); 
  console.log(data.ip.toString()); 

  retrieved_entity_ip = data.ip.toString();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's working so well until some clients were being shown errors and according to the logs it was because their IP address was missing. I narrowed it down to their browser extension, [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en), which was preventing the script from running.

Is there a more reliable way to do this without having to do any upgrade to paid tiers?

Comment: Your API treats IPs as credentials?

Comment: @GuerricP. yes. its in their [documentation](https://docs.fundamerica.com/#15c00406-a1f3-4a9b-a0d2-eaa648b8e6a4) so I believe I can share it as well.

Comment: Interesting. I don't get what's the purpose, and how they validate this address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript

Comment: No. That's where I got my current answer as posted in my question

Comment: In that event, I would encourage you to throw an error if the client can’t connect to your external service, with a message telling them to disable their network-blocking extensions.

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd do just that. I would even send a local IP just to get this working. But it needs a legit IP retrieved in a background process.

Comment: You could host your own ipify server. ipify is blacklisted https://github.com/rdegges/ipify-api/issues/18. you'd probably fly under the radar

Comment: Where do you see anything about an IP address in that API documentation?  I don't see it at your link.

Comment: @Brad Click view more on the "example request" on the right. The field name is "ip_address"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use public services which are [not blacklisted](https://easylist.to/easylist/easyprivacy.txt) by ad blockers, like https://www.myexternalip.com/json but eventually it can also be blacklisted, it's not under your control.

The most reliable way to *reduce* the risk of using a service that can be blacklisted would be building your own server as suggested in descriptions or keeping an updated list of alternative services in case of failed requests. Probably you won't get rid of your "problem" without spending some money.

Comment: Does this have any limitations? Something like 400 requests a day?

Comment: @ProsyArceno according to the service, "if you exceed the rate limit of 30 requests/minute, you will receive status code 429". This is per IP, so since your script is on the client side, I wouldn't worry about that, unless you have many users behind an internet gateway.

Comment: That's fine. I'll use this for now thanks